# What does reverse lexicographic order mean?

Tags: order-theory

What does reverse lexicographic order mean?

I met it when learning about `Graded reverse lexicographic order`. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial_order#Lexicographic_order) is the definition:

> Graded reverse lexicographic order (grevlex, or degrevlex for degree reverse lexicographic order) compares the total degree first, then uses a reverse lexicographic order as tie-breaker

But I was not able to find a definition for a reverse lexicographic order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To continue exactly at the point you ended your quote:

> but it *reverses* the outcome of the lexicographic comparison so that lexicographically larger monomials of the same degree are considered to be degrevlex smaller

Comment: So, does it mean the following: monomial `a` is larger than monomial `b` with respect to a reverse lexicographic order if and only if `a` is smaller than `b` with respect to a lexicographic order?

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov Only if both monomials have the same degree.